# On which condition will IllegalStateException be thrown?

Tags: java, exception, iterator, illegalstateexception

When working with an iteration, in which condition will `IllegalStateException` be thrown? I'm working on an assignment and it's multiple-choice:

a) calling `remove` after calling `next`
b) calling `next` after calling `previous`
c) calling `remove` after calling `remove`
d) calling `remove` after calling `previous`

What I found in the "API docs" is that if the `next` method has not yet been called, or the `remove` method has already been called after the last call to the `next` method.

So the answer then must be "a", but I'm told it's wrong. Why is my reasoning wrong, and what's the correct answer?

Comment: omg ! :) c seems more than indicated. :) But, next time, would you mind giving some context ?

Comment: @Snicolas I know, right? This removing after something was a little disturbing. "IllegalStateException signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time."

Comment: okay next time i will try to give you some context. sorry! thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You have a list `[a, b, c, d, e]`.  A pointer `N` starts out pointing at nothing.  This is the standard starting position for an iterator in Java.

Scenario A) -  call `next`, `N` is now pointing at `a`.  Call `remove`, `a` is gone and the list is `[b, c, d, e]`, `N` is pointing at nothing.

Scenario B) Call `previous`, `N` is now pointing at `e`.  Call `next`, `N` is now pointing at `a`.

Scenario C) Call `next`, `N` is pointing at `a`.  Call `remove`, `a` is gone, `N` is pointing at nothing.  Call `remove,`IllegalStateException`is thrown.`N` is pointing at nothing, so nothing can be removed.

Scenario D) Call `previous`, `N` is pointing at `e`.  Call `remove`, `e` is gone, `N` is pointing at nothing.

Scenario E) Call `remove`, `N` is pointing at nothing, so `IllegalStateException` is thrown.